# the prototype of dprintf (stdio.h)

Tags: printf, stdio

I'm trying to understand a program which makes calls to the function dprintf.

According to this link, https://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf, the function requires a file descriptor as its first argument.
However, the program I have calls dprintf this way:

dprintf("%5d ",vals[i][j]);

The code is here: https://github.com/kozyraki/phoenix/blob/master/phoenix-2.0/tests/pca/pca-pthread.c

I cannot find any reference to such a prototype for dprintf. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source file `phoenix/phoenix-2.0/tests/pca/pca-pthread.c` in
which `dprintf` appears includes `phoenix/phoenix-2.0/include/stddefines.h`,
in which you will find:

```
/* Debug printf */
#define dprintf(...) fprintf(stdout, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)